# How to refer to the .GlobalEnv of the session using callr::r

Tags: r, scope, callr

My understanding of `callr::r` is that the function I am providing is evaluated in a new session of `R`. If (for whatever reason) I want to keep the `.GlobalEnv` of this session, I thought I could do it like this:

```r
i_am_defined_on_global_level <- "here"
res <- callr::r(function() .GlobalEnv)
names(res)
# [1] "res"                          ".Random.seed"                
# [3] "i_am_defined_on_global_level"
```

But apparently `.GlobalEnv` within the anonymous function refers to the global environment of the **calling environment** (otherwise I would not see `i_am_defined_on_global_level`).

So how would I return the `.GlobalEnv` of the session in which the function is called?

### Background

I have a large Rmarkdown document and because of current bugs in Rstudio I cannot run [`run all chunks`](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11995) as I have non R chunks in my document. Thus, I have to run each chunk "by hand" which is rather cumbersome.

Thus, I wanted to call `render` not via the `knit` button, but from the command line, where I have control over the environment in which the document is rendered and thus could keep all intermediate results. I thought it would be a good idea to do so in a new session to avoid name conflicts, thus I wanted to rely on `callr::r`:

```r
render_report <- function(report = "myreport.Rmd",
                          report_dir = here::here("report")) {
   report_env <- callr::r(function(report, report_dir) {
      rmarkdown::render(file.path(report_dir, report), 
                        output_dir = report_dir,
                        envir = globalenv())
      globalenv()
   }, list(report = report, 
           report_dir = report_dir),
   show = TRUE,
   spinner = FALSE)
   report_env
}

results <- render_report()
```

But results refers then only to the original `GlobalEnv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Edited to correct the first sentence.]
The problem is that `.GlobalEnv` is saved in a weird way.  It just refers to the current global environment, whatever that is.  So anything you create in your function will disappear, and `res` will point to your current global environment.

To see the globals in the callr::r environment, I think you'll have to copy them to a new environment and return that.  E.g.

```r
i_am_defined_on_global_level <- "here"
res <- callr::r(function() {
  i_am_in_the_callr_global_env <<- "there"
  returnenv <- as.list(globalenv())
  list2env(returnenv)
  })
names(res)
#> [1] "i_am_in_the_callr_global_env"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm. DO you have by any chance any reference docs where this rather weired behaviour is explained? I thought because of lazy evaluation `globalenv` is not evaluated but before it is called - in this moment it should refer to the global env of `callr`. So for some very strange reason, it seems to be evaluated before which is very counterintuitive. So any docs with this respect would be helpful. How did you find out?

Comment: I think the weirdness is mainly to do with serialization.  The R Internals manual lists objects that are special this way:  "Some objects are written as if they were SEXPTYPEs: such pseudo-SEXPTYPEs cover R_NilValue, R_EmptyEnv, R_BaseEnv, R_GlobalEnv, R_UnboundValue, R_MissingArg and R_BaseNamespace."  (The "R_" prefix refers to the C variable for the object.)